# how to modify the local xml with powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load(“http://nykdev101.us.net.intra/carlos/amoncalltracker-temp-3-2011.nsf/%28XMLView%29?OpenAgent&view=%28StaffDetailsByRotation%29”)
$xml = [xml]($doc)
$xml.Save("C:/TEMP/data.xml")
```

what I wrote is just save a same xml from remote url

this is the oringnal .xml file:

```
<xml version="1.0">
  -<VIEW ID="DBA58FEDF4D">
   -<DOC ID="A1D46BAD94">
     -<APPNAME>
     <![CDATA[ 1042%2OPRC]]>
     </APPNAME>
    <RTN/>
  -<SUPPORTCONTACTNAME>
     -<![CDATA[Emelie%20Pierrel]]>
   </SUPPORTCONTACTNAME>
  -<STCONTACT>
     -<![CDATA[]]>
   </STCONTACT>
  -<NDCONTACT>
     -<![CDATA[]]>
   </NDCONTACT>
   -<RDCONTACT>
     -<![CDATA[201-850-6560]]>
   </RDCONTACT>
   -<THCONTACT>
   </THCONTACT>
   -<OFFICECONTACT>
   </OFFICECONTACT>
  </DOC>
```

and I wanna remove all the '-' and ',' which may cause display error.

how will I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xmltext = Get-Content C:/TEMP/data.xml
$pattern = "-<"
$new = "<"
foreach($line in $xmltext) {
    $replace = [regex]::replace($line, $pattern, $new)
    echo $replace
}
```

Comment: it does not work, I wanna remove all the "-" in numbers, can you help me out?

Comment: Left out a line in the code.  Just fixed it.  Please try again.  If you still have problems, please include the output and/or error messages.

Comment: That's not going to work either.  Updated the code to operate on your saved file.

Comment: Another note:  I think that this line:  $xml = [xml]($doc) in your code is redundant to the first line.

Comment: [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$xd = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xd.Load(“http://nykdev101.us.net.intra/carlos/amoncalltracker-temp-3-2011.nsf/%28XMLView%29?OpenAgent&view=%28StaffDetailsByRotation%29”)    
$nodelist = $xd.selectnodes("/VIEW/DOC")
foreach($Node in $nodelist){
$number $Node.selectSingleNode("OFFICECONTACT").selectSingleNode("CDATA").get_InnerXml()
$new_n = $number -replace("-","")
}
$xml.Save("C:/TEMP/data2.xml")

Comment: why system said error on select the value of officecontact, how can I get the value in the tag of <CDATA>? it's not a regular tag right?

Comment: Should just be $xml.xml.VIEW.DOC.OFFICECONTACT.  In any case, according to your XML file, OFFICECONTACT is empty.

Comment: cool! it works! one more question, how to remove all the new line and tab in a xml? below are my code:    

function Replace-String($find, $replace)
{
   (Get-Content C:/Temp/data6.xml) | 
   Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $find, $replace} | 
   Set-Content C:/Temp/data6.xml 
} 
Replace-String "\n"  ""

Comment: Are you sure it works?  You haven't upvoted the answer or marked it as solved.